# reading uint16_t from bit stream

Tags: c++, header, stream, ip

I'm attempting to read a uint16_t from a u_char stream pointer (which happens to point to an ip header) but am having some difficulty getting a rational result.

Right now when I run:

```
uint16_t len16 = *stream;
```

or when I run the following, in case there is a discrepancy between the network and host byte order:

```
uint16_t len16 = *stream;
len16 = ntohs(len16);
```

I do not get the expected result in the uint16_t. However when I run:

```
uint8_t total_len1, total_len2;
uint16_t total_len;

//get length1
total_len1 = *stream;

//advance pointer
stream += sizeof(uint8_t);

//get length2
total_len2 = *stream;

//advance pointer
stream += sizeof(uint8_t);
```

I get the results I am expecting in total_len1 and total_len2 in hex format. So what is going on here and how can I read this value directly into a uint16_t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading `*stream` will get the value of one element of `stream` (a `u_char` or `uint8_t`). You want to read an `uint16_t` from `stream`. In this case you will have to recast it's type to read it as if it was an array of `uint16_t`.

```
uint16_t len16 = *(uint16_t *)stream;
len16 = ntohs(len16);
```

Whats going on in memory:

`stream` points to this sequence of bytes:

```
| byte 1  | byte 2  | byte 3  | byte 4  | byte 5  | byte 6  | ...
| uint8_t | uint8_t | uint8_t | uint8_t | uint8_t | uint8_t | ...
```

`stream` is an array of `uint8_t` so by reading `stream` elements you read one byte at a time.

Now recasting `stream` type to be an array of `uint16_t`, you can read the bytes in pairs forming 16-bit values:

```
| byte 1  | byte 2  | byte 3  | byte 4  | byte 5  | byte 6  | ...
|     uint16_t      |     uint16_t      |     uint16_t      | ...
```

Be careful when using `u_char`, this type is not a C++ standard and its size may vary from a compiler to another.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Is there a way to tell the compiler an explicit length for u_char? The library I'm using to get the stream gives it as a const u_char stream.

Comment: I don't know. I think Microsoft Visual C++ may vary this from 8 to 16 depending if you've set your project to use multi-byte strings or not. Better just use `uint8_t` instead, this way you make sure you are using a 8-bits variable.